# pgadmin unable to connect to server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

when I Tried creating a connection with local sever by pgAdmin4 I couldnt I got this error message"pgAdmin unable to connect to server. Connection timeout expired" when I was creating the database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGiTh.png)
Regards.

I checked the internet connection and closed both of realtime defender and firewall... but couldnt open the local host on my pc. This is the first time I am using pgAdmin4 so maybe the issue is simple but I couldnt solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Best regard every one and hope to be your time good, I could solve the issue was have by my self, the issue was I didnt installed full needed files for it(I hope my solve assist any one want to begaine on this program).
Hope you have a good time.
Mohammad HAJJAR.